# Cut a mesh with knife tool and separate

Tags: knife-tool, bisect

I am pretty new to blender, trying to cut a mesh in different pieces. I know I can cut a mesh and then separate the mesh using the bisect tool, but I don't want to cut the plane, I want to separate based on a cut I made earlier. I have already made the cut using the cut-through function, but I am a bit lost once I have made the cut.

I want to be able to select one of either sides and separate it in two different meshes, but so far no luck. The picture is seen from above, but I want to select all the vertices left from the drawn line and separate them, thus having 2 different objects.

[image]

Comment: Once you've cut, press V to rip the mesh, then put your cursor over the left or right part, press L to select. To separate as a new object, press P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a demo of what @[moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) has stated in his comment. In *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>K</kbd> to start [`Knife Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html) then make your cut and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (aka Return Key) to confirm the cut. Leave the cut vertices highlighted while returning to *Select Box* mode. Then press <kbd>V</kbd> to [`Rip Vertices`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/rip_vertices.html) and then immediately press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the Rip operation. Then hover over any side of the mesh you want to separate and press <kbd>L</kbd> to [`Select Linked`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/linked.html) faces. Press <kbd>P</kbd> *> Selection* to [`Separate`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/separate.html) the selection into its own object. Now you can <kbd>tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode*. Notice you have separated the mesh into 2 objects.

[image]

Comment: Make sure all your vertices in the cut are highlighted